# Is there a way to block 3rd party software from taking control over the keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I'm using a website that use the [Artistscope](http://www.artistscope.com) plugin to protect its contents, one of the annoying things it does in order to limit the user is taking control over the keyboard, so the user keystrokes are useless.

Is there a way to "protected" the keyboard so that only windows can control it?

Comment: It sounds like it just doesn't accept keyboard commands. You can type in other places just fine while that website is open?

Comment: @Rob: No, it blocks the keyboard in general, you can't type no where.

Comment: I am not about to install it :-) can you tell at what level it works at?  Fire up a on screen keyboard OSK.exe, does it work or did they take your mouse too?

Comment: @Psycogeek: Great idea using the OSK, I actually believed it will work. but! they blocked it as well!. I can start it, but clicking the keys in it will do nothing. I guess they register to all the keyboard events and block them.

Comment: Are you trying to get access to the protected content, or just be able to use your keyboard?  Personally I'd avoid any site that required me to install a plugin that had that kind of scope, but I'm guessing there's some circumstance that's forcing you to use it?

Comment: @Geoff: It is an educational website that has video explanations of mathematics. Yes i'm forced to use it since its content suited to my college. Once you login to watch the videos, the keyboard is dead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that enclosing the browser inside something like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) would work, and is probably worth the effort if you will be using this website a lot.  If it works, it will at least let you continue using your main system, while the browser (with its locked keyboard) runs embedded.

Similar options would be Microsoft's [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx) (on Windows 7, which I don't use, I believe this would be [XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx)) and possibly [Qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Index.html).

Comment: Interesting, I'll give it a try and let you know..

Comment: Appears to be another issue, I can login to the website only through the PC I registered from. It detects the VM as a different machine and won't let me login.

Comment: Contact them and let them know that you've got a new computer. They should have you register again with the new computer, I'd guess. They can't just stop people from changing computers if their's dies, I'd assume.

Comment: But what you don't tell them is that the computer you re-register from is virtual.

Comment: Registered the website trough the VM, and it works great. Thanks!